# Serialization using Json.NET

Tags: c#, json

using JavaScriptSerializer we serialize like this:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

string requestData = serializer.Serialize(new
{
   EventID = 1,
   SubscriberID = 5,
   ToList = "abcd",
   TemplateParamVals = ""
 });
```

How do I do the same using Json.NET?
The var serializer will be used in UploadDataTaskAsync method of WebClient.

Comment: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to serialize to a string, you can use the static methods in the `JsonConvert` class.

```
string requestData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
   EventID = 1,
   SubscriberID = 5,
   ToList = "abcd",
   TemplateParamVals = ""
 });
```

To serialize to a `JsonWriter` or `TextWriter`, use the `JsonSerializer` class.

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
serializer.Serialize(writer, obj);
```